# Informatica wants me to re-install because of old version, but no newer version available

Tags: data-loader, informatica

I opened today the Informatica Data Loader (Free) tab, and wanted to sync some data.
But then I got this message:

> You have an older version of the Informatica Data Loader Service managed application. Please re-install the managed package from Salesforce AppExchange.

http://img59.imageshack.us/img59/8240/screenshot20121115at173.png

So what I did I clicked on the link, which leads me to the AppExchange. I uninstalled the actual version and installed the one from the AppExchange, but it was the same one and I get the same error message. Same if I just try to update it. The only version is 3.6, I can't do an update to something higher as the tab suggests.

Any ideas from you? Is anyone else encountering this problem?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This was a Salesforce bug that has been fixed. Everything is fine now. Details here:

https://community.informatica.com/docs/DOC-2923

Answer (score 0):

Have you contacted the App. developer? Informatic? They should be able to provide some insight, and if so, hopefully a work-around.

It sounds like they have failed to maintain their AppExchange listing with the package uploads in their packaging org, which may or may not be publicly listed.

Comment: Good point! I wanted to use social media instead of email, but couldn't find an Informatica facebook page. 
But now I sent them an email anyways, and I will post the answer here when I receive one.